# Regular expression with multiple groups can't catch parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

Here is my string sample:
"#31,456 in this category (Top 100 of category)"

My tasks are:

1. get rid of first hashtag (make sure the sentence begins with hashtag)
2. Take all the digits after hashtag (digits may or may not have semicolon in between)
3. Take all the text which is after 31,456 digits and before first parenthesis.
4. get rid of parenthesis with the text inside.

Here the regex I came up with.

```
(^\#)(\d+[,]?\d+)(.*)([\(+])
```

Expected result:

Group 2 - 31,456

Group 3 - in this category

Basically I need to take the first digits and the sentence after it, grouped separately.
This regex does the job only if the string contains parenthesis. But there are cases when it doesn't contain, and in that case it doesn't take anything at all.

Please spread some light. I am doing the task with python 3, if that matters.

Comment: So, what is the expected result?

Comment: I have added in the question. Thanks for noting

Comment: Maybe they should be in Group 1 and 2? See https://regex101.com/r/2nyX7M/1

Comment: That seem to perfectly do the job. Submit it as an answer please

Comment: It's not clear what you expect `[\(+]` to do but what it actually does is match one character which can be `\` or `(` or `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^#(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*([^(]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2nyX7M/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `#` - a hash symbol
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits and an optional sequence of `,` followed with 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `([^(]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `(`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Xk1bZb):

```
import re
rx = r"^#(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*([^(]*)"
s = "#31,456 in this category (Top 100 of category)"
m = re.search(rx, s)
if m:
    print("Group 1: {}; Group 2: {}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2)))
# => Group 1: 31,456; Group 2: in this category
```

Comment: I just don't get why \s - whitespace char is being included in group 2 ?

Comment: Accepted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MherHarutyunyan Whitespace is not included in Group 2 as it is outside of the second pair of unescaped parentheses. Glad to help.

Comment: Yea I just get a whitespace as a last character in group 2, I thought it comes from \s, but apparently it comes as a last character of the string before parenthesis

Comment: You may `.strip()` the whitespace. `m.group(2).strip()`. Well, you may also try `r"^#(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*([^(]*[^(\s])"`.

Comment: .strip() did the job. Thank you.

Comment: Or use lookback assertion: `^#(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*([^(]*)(?<=\S)`.

Comment: @Silvar Then, it is just the same as `r"^#(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*([^(]*[^(\s])"`, but with a lookbehind. Anyway, thanks for contributing.